# How to split a string by space and some special character in java

Tags: java, regex

Consider the string `.more opr (&x NE &m),&n+1` 
All i need is split this string into following parts `.more`,`opr`,`(`,`&x`,`NE`,`&m`,`)` , `,` , `&n`, `+`, `1`.In short I need to split on spaces and some special symbols like ( ) , and arithmetic operators.
How to write regex expression for split() in java to achieve this.

Comment: You contained `(`, `)` and `+` as output parts. Do you really need it in output? If not, I think it would be good to edit question.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to find the correct regular expression. I use https://regex101.com/.

Comment: @Przemysław Moskal yes i need them in output. My main aim is to access words starting with '&' and '.' then replacing them with something else while keeping the rest of the string same.

Answer (score 2):

Split on space or either side of brackets or operators:

```
str.split(" |(?<=[,()+-])|(?<! )(?=[,()+-])")
```

---

The output of:

```
String str = ".more opr (&x NE &m),&n+1";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split(" |(?<=[,()+-])|(?<! )(?=[,()+-])")));
```

is:

```
[.more, opr, (, &x, NE, &m, ), ,, &n, +, 1]
```

Or more clearly:

```
Arrays.stream(str.split(" |(?<=[,()+-])|(?<! )(?=[,()+-])")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

outputs:

```
.more
opr
(
&x
NE
&m
)
,
&n
+
1
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's 100% what OP was looking for, as he contained `(`, `+` and `)` as output parts.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal that's exactly what this does - (, + and ) are retained as output parts

Comment: Wow, in that case sorry for that unnecessary comment and +1 for the solution. Thank you for giving explanation.

Comment: As I understand what is happening in the rest of the regex provided by you, I can't figure out what last "OR" part of your regex means (this one:`(?<! )(?=[,()+-])`) . Is there any possibility to get some explanations on how should I "read" it? PS. Using streams looks great in that case. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for the answer.Can you help me understand this regex statement.It would be really helpful if you can link material to study the regex.